# Unable to convert BufferedImage to image java

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to set a image to my image view, and tried converting the image from a buffered image. However, before compiling I get an error saying " Type Mismatch: Cannot convert writeableImage to image". Can anyone explain why this is so and how to resolve this problem? Thank you :)

```
  BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
  Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
  myImageView.setImage(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably imported `java.awt.Image` instead of `javafx.scene.image.Image`.

Also, depending on context, it may be better to directly construct an `Image` via `new Image(String url)`.

Comment: tried doing this and i get a awt image. I'm trying to work with both javafx.scene.image.Image and java.awt.Image at the same time

Comment: @DavidLie Not sure what you are talking about. You need to give a [mcve].

Comment: nvm! I just rewrote the whole thing without using java.awt.Image! Thank you!

Comment: @DavidLie If you do need to use types of the same name in the same file, just import one and use the fully qualified type name, e.g. `javafx.scene.image.Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);`